# embedding a dynamic 3d object to your website

Tags: python

im sorry if i keep asking the same question but i really really need to figure this one out. 
the problems i currently have are:
1. a python library that will allow me to create a custom dynamic 3d model
   ---> i tried vpython (extremely good) but found that images I make there cannot exactly be embedded in a site

1. a method to embed the said dynamic 3d model in a website such that said object moves in (almost) "real time" upon user input

Comment: You mean something like the ancient/dead VRML stuff?

Comment: im not really familiar with vrml but from what ive googled and read, it seems to be pretty similar. since you mentioned that its dead sir can you point me in the right direction as to which programs i can use instead of vrml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With html5/canvas2d you can get reasonable stuff in realtime...

for example see this simple [icosahedron](http://goo.gl/dlY63) (with a readable source) or this [compressed 4k demo](http://goo.gl/fpxng) I wrote as experiments.

they work on Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera and Nexus One browsers. I didn't test other browsers.

An interactive version of the icosahedron can be seen [here](http://goo.gl/iFxf6).

Comment: oh wow! this is exactly what i need! can i configure this to move according to user input? im going to try and model a car. the only movement i will be doing is rotating it about the x,y,z axes by some angle (user input).

Comment: I added an interactive version of the icosahedron. Also now uses matrix math (implementing the ball control without is annoying).